# Can I install ubuntu 12.04 lts using ubuntu 14.04 lts trail version?

Tags: 12.04, boot, 14.04, filesystem

So my ubuntu 12.04 files are corrupted so i got ubuntu 14.04 on a flash drive and I am currently booting using the drive. So I was wondering is there and way by which I can reinstall ubuntu 12.04 lts using the same drive or using ubuntu 14.04 trail version. Just for the record, I do not want ubuntu 14.04 lts. I don't want to install it. Please answer. Thank you

Comment: there is not need to reinstall again you can also repair your file system. Currently What error message got after your system bootup.

Comment: Nothing. The screen is just a purple blank

Comment: Booting from Ubuntu 14.04 from flash drive. have you got your hard disk partition.

Comment: what? i dont get it but i think the answer is no

Comment: Detect your HDD in your BIOS settings then boot your computer. If you got blank screen and did not got any error then press TAB key or Error Key. see what happen

Comment: a littel help here! i dont get it

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean-install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. You can use a USB to install 12.04 as well. I have tried it myself and its all fine